# trying to have a responsive design for the items using media query and flexbox , but it is not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, media-queries

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:700px) {
  .item {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">content</div>
  <div class="item">content</div>
</div>
```

I was expecting a responsive design that when the screen is under `700px`, the items should be columnar and when the screen is wider than `700px`, the items should be in a row and their width should be `50%`. However, it looks like just `width: 50%;` is applying.

This is the image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to account for the `.item` elements' `border-left-width`, `border-right-width`, `margin-left` and `margin-right`. In your code at viewport width greater than `700px`, each `.item` element takes up the following amount of horizontal space:

```
50% + 10px + 10px + 1px + 1px = 50% + 22px
 ↑      ↑      ↑     ↑     ↑
`width` │`margin-right`    │
        │            │     │
  `margin-left`      │`border-right-width`
                     │
          `border-left-width`
```

Thus, for 2 items of `50% + 22px` width, this would be `44px` greater than `100%`, the width of `.container`, and thus will continue to wrap at viewport width greater than `700px`.

To have them display in the same row, consider adjusting their `width`, compensating for the extra space from their horizontal border widths and horizontal margins by subtracting this extra space, `22px`, from `50%`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:700px) {
  .item {
    width: calc(50% - 22px);
  }
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">content</div>
  <div class="item">content</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could apply `flex-wrap: nowrap` on `.container`. This forces the `.item` elements to display in a row, by shrinking their widths to fit:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:700px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">content</div>
  <div class="item">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using `min-width: 700px` which means that the styles inside the media query will apply when the screen width is at least **700px**. However, you want the opposite: you want the styles to apply when the screen width is less than **700px**. To do that, you need to use `max-width: 700px` instead.

You are using `flex-direction: column` for the container, which means that the items will be stacked vertically. However, you want the opposite: you want the items to be stacked horizontally. To do that, you need to use `flex-direction: row` instead.

You need to change your media query and flex-direction values as follows:

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  flex-wrap:wrap ;
  flex-direction: row; /* change this to row */
}
.item{
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width:700px) { /* change this to max-width */
  .item{
   width: 50%;
  }
  .container{
   flex-direction: column; /* change this to column */
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The `.item` elements will still be displayed in a single column, whatever the viewport width, [as evidenced by this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ah517buz/).